# Mongoose date query not working properly on heroku production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I have that following query that works absolutely fine on my local, but the in the production (live), i am not getting the expected results.

```
var startDay = new Date();
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var endDay = new Date();
end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

CheckBill.find({
        status: true,
        nextDueDate: {
            "$gte": startDay,
            "$lt": endDay
        }
    })
    .populate('customer')
    .then(function(docs) {
        console.log(docs)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Please help

Comment: If you expect help, then you really need to show some sample documents, the input parameters ( values for `startDay` and `endDay` ) and what you expect to happen against what is currently happening. *"am not getting the expected results."* really is not enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that, please have a look now.

Comment: Well I did ask for "documents you expect to match" and I don't see those. We **really need to**. I do see that you are constructing `Date` objects from "localtime" values, and it's likely the conversion to UTC is different in the production environment than on your local machine, both in data and the timezone adjustment for the hosted location. So you probably really mean `start.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`, or at least you really **"should"** mean that. If you didn't understand that, then there's a good change the data is messed up in production as well.

Comment: Also `endDay = new Date(start.valueOf() +(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))`. Much cleaner and also corrects your other bug as `$lt` would be excluding the last millisecond of the day based on the current code. You want *"less than the **start** of the next day"*.

Comment: actually this is my first prod project, so do you mean to set the timings in the `start.setUTCHours` format?

Comment: MongoDB stores **ALL** Date information as the UTC values. If it's server side code, you "should" really mean as UTC. The only time you use "localtime" is when the value comes from a UI, such as the browser, where it would then be converted "relative" to the present UTC time.

Comment: Thank you so much, so i shall use it as  `var start = new Date();
    start.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var end = new Date(start.valueOf() +(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    end.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);`